# angular-google-maps no api keys

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I was having trouble with my app getting the 'no api key' warning. I added this .config:

```
  .config(['uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider', function (GoogleMapApi) {
  GoogleMapApi.configure({
   key: 'AIzaSyCbRPhVlxgVwBC0bBOgyB-Dn_K8ONrxb_g',
   v: '3',
    libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
  });
  }])
```

This made the warning go away but I am still getting a blank page for my app instead of google maps. I am not getting any warning either so I can't figure out what's wrong but I think it must have to do with the API key not getting through. I am using this repo: https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps.

Here is the web page: http://alainwebdesign.ca/pl4/

Full JS file where I may have made a mistake:

```
(function (window, ng) {
    ng.module('app', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps', 'ui.router'])



  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider.state('location', {
          url: '/:lat/:lon',
          templateUrl: 'index.html',
          controller: 'MapsCtrl',
          resolve: {
              resolveMap: function (MapService, $stateParams) {
                  return MapService.getData($stateParams.lat, $stateParams.lon);
              }
          }
      });

  })

  .config(['uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider', function (GoogleMapApi) {
  GoogleMapApi.configure({
   key: 'AIzaSyCbRPhVlxgVwBC0bBOgyB-Dn_K8ONrxb_g',
   v: '3',
    libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
  });
  }])


    .controller('MapsCtrl', ['$scope', "uiGmapLogger", "uiGmapGoogleMapApi", "$interval", "$state", "$stateParams",
      function ($scope, $log, GoogleMapApi, $interval, $state, $stateParams) {
          $log.currentLevel = $log.LEVELS.debug;
          var center = { latitude: $stateParams.lat, longitude: $stateParams.lon };
          alert(center)
          Object.freeze(center);

          $scope.map = {
              center: center,
              pan: false,
              zoom: 16,
              refresh: false,
              events: {},
              bounds: {}
          };

          $scope.map.circle = {
              id: 1,
              center: center,
              radius: 500, //(current time - date lost)*km/hour
              stroke: {
                  color: '#08B21F',
                  weight: 2,
                  opacity: 1
              },

              fill: {
                  color: '#08B21F',
                  opacity: 0.5
              },
              geodesic: false, // optional: defaults to false
              draggable: false, // optional: defaults to false
              clickable: true, // optional: defaults to true
              editable: false, // optional: defaults to false
              visible: true, // optional: defaults to true
              events: {
                  dblclick: function () {
                      $log.debug("circle dblclick");
                  },
                  radius_changed: function (gObject) {
                      var radius = gObject.getRadius();
                      $log.debug("circle radius radius_changed " + radius);
                  }
              }
          }





          //Increase Radius:
          $interval(function () {
              $scope.map.circle.radius += 30; //dynamic var
              $state.transitionTo('location', { //location is the state name
                  center: $stateParams.center,
                  radius: $scope.map.circle.radius
              },
    {
        notify: false
    });
          }, 1000); //end of interval function


      } ]); //end of controller

})(window, angular);
```

And index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="example/assets/stylesheets/example.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="website_libs/dev_deps.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/nmccready/angular-simple-logger/0.0.1/dist/index.js"></script><script src="dist/angular-google-maps_dev_mapped.js"></script>
    <script src="getLoc.js"></script>
    <script src="searchRadius.js"></script>


    <title>Pet Locate</title>

    <!--NEW STUFF FROM TOM-->


</head>

<body style="height: 100%">



<div data-ng-controller="MapsCtrl" ng-if="map.center !== undefined" style="height: 100%">
    <ui-gmap-google-map 
                        center='map.center'
                        zoom='map.zoom'
                        draggable='map.draggable'
                        dragging='map.dragging'
                        refresh='map.refresh'
                        options='map.options'
                        events='map.events'
                        pan='map.pan'>


        <ui-gmap-circle 
                        center='map.circle.center'
                        radius='map.circle.radius'
                        fill='map.circle.fill'
                        stroke='map.circle.stroke'
                        clickable='map.circle.clickable'
                        draggable='map.circle.draggable'
                        editable='map.circle.editable'
                        visible='map.circle.visible'
                        events='map.circle.events'>

        </ui-gmap-circle>


    </ui-gmap-google-map>

</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you have the `<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'></ui-gmap-google-map>` element on your page?

Comment: Yes, I just added index.html if you want to see the rest too, maybe it has something to do with: ng-if="map.center !== undefined" ?

Comment: That what I was thinking. I'd try removing that for now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Tom Coughlin for your comment, it made me realize the problem was I wasn't returning a valid 'center' property, so the ng-if statement in index.html stopped the page from being displayed.